# How to read multiple CSV files with different data in C#?

Tags: c#, csv, console-application

I am writing a console application which reads multiple CSV files from a single folder using SmartXLS library. Currently, my App is able to read CSV files with similar data from a folder but my requirement for the App is to read all the files with similar/different data one after the other. Kindly, help me with this.

Code:

```
public void GetData()
        {
                int count = 0;

                 Tokens = new List<Token>();

                 var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\projects", "*.csv");

                foreach (string file in files)
                {
                    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                    {
                        SmartXLS.WorkBook WB = new WorkBook();
                        WB.readCSV(file);

                        DataTable dt = WB.ExportDataTable();
                        string dtSTR;
                        DataRow dr;

                        for (int i = 1; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                        {
                            dr = dt.Rows[i];

                            try
                            {
                                 dtSTR = dr[0].ToString();
                                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dtSTR)) continue;

                                var tkn = new Token();
                                tkn.Usagedate = ParseDateTime(dtSTR);
                                tkn.Product_name = dr[1].ToString();
                                tkn.Product_Version = dr[2].ToString();
                                tkn.Userid = dr[3].ToString();

                                Tokens.Add(tkn);
                                count++;

                                Console.WriteLine("Read : " + count);

                                Console.WriteLine("    Reading : " + tkn.Usagedate + "," + tkn.Product_name + "," + tkn.Product_Version + "," + tkn.Userid);

                            }

                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {

                            }

                        }
                    }

                }
            }
```

Comment: whats the question?

Comment: How can I read CSV files with different column names from a single folder? @Seabizkit

Comment: By different, you also mean unknown at runtime? You need to have *some* understanding of the columns in these files, if you want to parse different columns as `DateTime`, `float`, or just use as `string`.

Comment: I have 3 different csv files in a folder with different columns. I want to know how can I read those three files one after the other? I want to parse them as a string. @Groo

Comment: How can I iterate and read through each file? @Groo

Comment: @Rev4: `Directory.EnumerateFiles` already gives you all files in the directory, you are iterating through them using the `foreach` loop, and reading each file separately using `WB.readCSV`.

Answer (score 1):

If you only have (as stated in the comments) 3 different kind of csv. 
Just create 3 models accordingly and use [CSVHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) to read the data.

Answer (score 0):

Read something in the filename or column structure that identify the structure type... so that you know how to interpret what is being read. 3 different CSV files, 3 different ways to interpret. write each and pass to respective method once the "format type: has been identified. Unfortunately there are no shortcuts, depends on how dynamic you want to make it, as to the level of work required.